# Question about predicates in prolog with an example

Tags: prolog

so if I have

```
highbmi(bmi>=25).
highbmi(bmi=<29.9)
has_bmi(person,27).
needscheckup(X):-has_bmi(X,bmi>=25).
```

do I have the right idea? I am new to this, but I want it to be able to see that the person has a bmi of 27, and needs a check up. Please do help, anything appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Prolog start with either an uppercase letter or an underscore. Moreover, Prolog is not a functional language and thus predicate arguments such as `bmi>=25` are not evaluated as a function call. Try instead:

```
high_bmi(BMI) :-
   25 =< BMI, BMI =< 29.9.

has_bmi(john_doe, 27).
has_bmi(jane_doe, 18).

needs_checkup(Person) :-
    has_bmi(Person, BMI),
    high_bmi(BMI).
```

Sample calls:

```
| ?- needs_checkup(Person).

Person = john_doe ? ;
no

| ?- needs_checkup(jane_doe).
no
```